# How can i use if needed the FileInfo[] or if needed the string[]?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 i have two buttons one to select files from directory single file or multiple files.
The second button is to select files from a directory to get all the files in a selected directory.

Now i have a class i'm using to upload the files/directories to my ftp:
At the top of the class i did:

```
public static DirectoryInfo d;
public static string[] files;
private FileInfo[] dirflist;
```

Then i'm using it in the event:

```
private void FtpProgress_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                dirflist = d.GetFiles();
                //if (dirflist.Length > 0)
                //{
                    foreach (string txf in files)
                    {
                        string fn = txf;//txf.Name;
                        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                        f = e.Argument as FtpSettings;
                        string UploadPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", f.Host, f.TargetFolder == "" ? "" : f.TargetFolder + "/", Path.GetFileName(fn));//f.SourceFile));
                        if (!UploadPath.ToLower().StartsWith("ftp://"))
                            UploadPath = "ftp://" + UploadPath;
                        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UploadPath);
                        request.UseBinary = true;
                        request.UsePassive = f.Passive;
                        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                        request.Timeout = 300000;
                        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(f.Username, f.Password);
                        long FileSize = new FileInfo(f.SourceFile).Length;
                        string FileSizeDescription = GetFileSize(FileSize);
                        int ChunkSize = 4096, NumRetries = 0, MaxRetries = 50;
                        long SentBytes = 0;
                        byte[] Buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
                        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                        {
                            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(f.SourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                            {
                                int BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                                while (BytesRead > 0)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        if (bw.CancellationPending)
                                            return;

                                        requestStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead);

                                        SentBytes += BytesRead;

                                        string SummaryText = String.Format("Transferred {0} / {1}", GetFileSize(SentBytes), FileSizeDescription);
                                        bw.ReportProgress((int)(((decimal)SentBytes / (decimal)FileSize) * 100), SummaryText);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                                        if (NumRetries++ < MaxRetries)
                                        {
                                            fs.Position -= BytesRead;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            throw new Exception(String.Format("Error occurred during upload, too many retries. \n{0}", ex.ToString()));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription));
                    }
                //}
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Status)
                {
                    case WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure:
                        ConnectionError = "Error: Please check the ftp address";
                        break;
                    case WebExceptionStatus.Timeout:
                        ConnectionError = "Error: Timout Request";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Now i'm doing loop over the string[] array.
Since i'm selecting multiple files only.

But there might be a case i will select a directory. And then i will need to use the DirectoryInfo(d variable) and the FileInfo[]

If i'm using the FileInfo[] then it's like that:

```
dirflist = d.GetFiles();
                if (dirflist.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo txf in dirfilist)
                    {
                        string fn = txf.Name;
```

But i don't want to copy over all the code again just for string[] or just for FileInfo[]
I want to make something that i will be able to use FileInfo[] with the foreach or the string[] in the foreach.

And maybe sometimes i will use both upload multiple files and then also to upload a directory with all the files inside.

So maybe it's better to duplicate the whole code and making using once string[] and once FileInfo[] ?
I mean to make two methods one will use FileInfo[] one string[]

Comment: just use `d.GetFileSystemInfos()` - did you look at all before asking the question?

Comment: I've read the Ftp sending process. I would divide the tasks in Functions. The While containing the CancellationPending handing would be a Function (returns 1 if file handled, 0 upon BW Cancellation, and perhaps -1 in case of Exception) I would also move the task to get File Information per File Path (or FileInfo) in a Function that returns a custom class with all required members (then just pass that class to a function that will handle the buffering) - For UI purpose, such class could contain the buffering, handle the FTP sending and raise events : chunck send, transfer complete, cancelled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How can i use if needed the* `FileInfo[]` *or if needed the* `string[]` *?*

```
private void SomeMethod(args)
{
    // ...

    /* Here I need a specific String Value, or Array of String Values
    but sometimes I got it from an array of File,
    and sometimes from an array of FileInfo... */

    // Call a Function that always returns an array of String
    files = GetMyFiles(args);

    // resume the job using only files...

    /* or replace the above that always manipulates an arrays of FileInfo-s
    if you must use FileInfo-s */
}
```

Then you can overload your function GetMyFiles by passing any argument you want.

```
string[] GetMyFiles(String DirectoryPath)
// Returns an Array of String that contains all the Files in the Directory.

string[] GetMyFiles(FileInfo MyFileInfo)
// Returns an Array of String with just one File Path.

string[] GetMyFiles()
// Opens a MultiSelect OpenFileDialog, 
// then returns the selected Files Path in an Array (or empty Array)

// ...
```

---

The other way : Slice your code in multiple parts, then decide which part you're going to use with a conditional check...

```
private void FtpProgress_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do the maximum you can do here...
    // ...

    if ImGoingToUseStringArray
    {
        string[] files = ....
        ResumeWithStringArray(files, sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
        FileInfo[] dirflist = ....
        ResumeWithFileInfo(dirfList, sender, e);
    }
}

private void ResumeWithStringArray(string[] files, object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    // you can also call another core Function from here
    sendMyFile(args)
}

private void ResumeWithFileInfo(FileInfo[] dirflist, object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    // you can also call another core Function from here
    sendMyFile(args)
}
```

---

Anyway, you'll have to use FileInfo to get the FileSize (required in File Transfer I assume) right ? However, you decide the moment you create that FileInfo **per File** (or are you using several FileInfo-s at the same time ?) If you think your code get too complicated with a list/array of FileInfo from the start, just creates each instance of FileInfo dynamically when it's required (slice your code in parts)

It seems to me the answer to your question only depends on your taste, or only require some changes in the way you're running the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Put all code that handles a single file into a separate method like this:

```
private void CopyFile(string fn)
{
   BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
   f = e.Argument as FtpSettings;
   ...
}
```

now decide wheter you want to do the file list stuff or the dir list stuff, and call your new method like this:

**File-List:**

```
foreach (string txf in files)
{
   this.CopyFile(txt);
}
```

**Dir-List:**

```
dirflist = d.GetFiles();
if (dirflist.Length > 0)
{
   foreach (FileInfo txf in dirfilist)
   {
      this.CopyFile(txt.Name);
   }
}
```